# How can i create multitasking between activities?

Tags: java, android

I want to display two activities at a time and can work on both simultaneously. Is it possible ? if possible please give me some example. I am working in android 2.2 froyo.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In android you can not display more than a single Activity at a time. So creating Multitasking between Activities is not possible.

Comment: i think we can display more than 1 activity when using fragments correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Yes. But you can pause  one and resume another. But both at the same time ,dont think its possible.

Comment: @ShashankKadne, i agree with you, but then it won't called mulltitasking :)

Comment: pause and resume other?? in fragments?? please refer this http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle

Comment: @droidhot i have heard about fragment but its not supported in 2.2 froyo

Comment: @Antarix it is supported in froyo with compatability package

Comment: @Lucifer is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: @Antarix: I was referring to Activities. OP wants multi tasking between two "different"  independent Activities....according to you, I should represent those two activities in two fragments in a single activity right? But then it defeats the whole purpose. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @ShashankKadne ya actually i saw this multitasking in `iPhone` app which i wanted to implement it in my android app.

Comment: @Antarix, iPhone is totally different Environment.

Comment: @Lucifer ya i know that but how can we bring such functionality in android that is what i am thinking